# add items from listbox to another VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following list, I need to select an item from the list" Liste de toute les lames", then by clickig on the button "Ajouter lames enService" the item will be added on the list" Lames en Service" :

[image]

The code :

```
Private Sub Ajout_Lame_S_Click()
Dim ws_Lame As Worksheet
Dim Modele As String
Dim dl As Integer
Modele = "Liste_Lame_" & Me.TextBox1.Value
If Me.ListBox_Lames.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox ("Veuillez choisir une lame de la liste de toutes les lames")
Else
    Set ws_Lame = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Modele)
    dl = ws_Lame.Range("A65530").End(xlUp).Row
    ws_Lame.Activate
    Nom_LamesS = Me.ListBox_Lames.Value
    ws_Lame.Cells(dl + 1, 5) = Nom_LamesS
    'Mettre a jour la liste
    For i = 2 To dl
        Me.ListBox_LamesS.AddItem ws_Lame.Range("E" & i)
    Next
End If
MsgBox ("Lame ajoutée a la liste lames en Service!")
End Sub
```

I dont know what's wrong with my code but nothing is being added on my target list.

Comment: Debug your code ([Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)), go through it step by step using F8. In each step check the values of your variables. This way you can find out where it goes wrong. Give it a try.

Comment: I replaced A655330 by E65330 and it is working now :)

Comment: Note that newer versions of Excel have more than `65530`. Never hard code this number or you will run into issues soon or later. Instead use `dl = ws_Lame.Cells(ws_Lame.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row` to find the last used row in column E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your question literally, if you want to copy a line from one listbox to another, the code you need to use is this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim I As Long
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem
            For I = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1, I) = .List(.ListIndex, I)
            Next I
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it did help me a lot, I won't specify the number of rows anymore cause it's always causing me problems and I didnt know who to define dl deferently. Thanks